# Printing the largest odd number

Tags: python

For this question, I want to try to print the largest odd number until the user enters 0. However, when I try to test my code, why does my code return 3, when 5 is supposed to be the largest odd number that is returned. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Here are my test cases:

```
biggestOdd()

Enter a positive integer: 5
Enter a positive integer: 4
Enter a positive integer: 3
Enter a positive integer: 2
Enter a positive integer: 0
3


def biggestOdd():
biggest_odd_num = None
n = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
while n != 0:
    n = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
    if (n % 2 != 0 and (biggest_odd_num is None or n > biggest_odd_num)):
        biggest_odd_num = n
if biggest_odd_num:
    return biggest_odd_num
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: The first statement in your `while` loop immediately overwrites the first `n` entry (where you entered `5`). The next-largest odd number is `3`.

Answer (score 1):

The first input `n` is never used.

```
def biggestOdd():
    biggest_odd_num = 0
    while True:
        n = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
        if not n:
            break
        if n % 2 != 0 and n > biggest_odd_num:
            biggest_odd_num = n
    return biggest_odd_num
```